# WSO2 API Manager UserInformationRecoveryService is not listed in admin services

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup WSO2 API Manager version 2.
I wanted to send an email for user activation. After going through documentation and blogs I came to know that I need UserInformationRecoveryService.

But when I start my WSO2 API Manager with OSGI console flag to run listAdminServices command, in the list I could not get the name ad url for UserInformationRecoveryService.

Can someone guide me on how to install this service in WSO2 API Manager version 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UserInformationRecoveryService is not included by default in API Manager. You need to install that feature. Please refer this article [[1]](http://chamaleedesilva.blogspot.com/2015/10/enabling-user-password-recovery-for.html).